# Not able to get the Members of the AD Group

Tags: c#, .net, azure, active-directory

I am trying to read all the members of specific group in .net Console Application using Graph API but its giving me `"Invalid object identifier 'TEMP_USER'."` error.I am not getting what i am missing here.Below is the code function to get the Member of AD Group

```
IGroupFetcher retrievedGroupFetcher = (Group)await activeDirectoryClient.Groups
                             .GetByObjectId(GroupName.DisplayName).ExecuteAsync();

IPagedCollection<IDirectoryObject> members = null;
try
{
   members = retrievedGroupFetcher.Members.ExecuteAsync().Result;
}
catch(Exception ex){}
```

And here is how i am calling the function..

```
Group GroupName = new Group();
GroupName.DisplayName = "TEMP_USER";
objADOperations.GetAllUsersOfGroup(GroupName).Wait();
```

Please help me in correcting the error..Thanks..

Comment: Where do you get the error?

Comment: @stuartd I am getting error at the very first line of the Posted Code..

Comment: That cast to `Group` looks odd. Do you have a user in your AD called TEMP_USER?

Comment: @stuartd Yes its there ..

Comment: @stuartd This is async Task and i am calling it from Console application like `Group GroupName = new Group();
            GroupName.DisplayName = "TEMP_USER";
            objADOperations.GetAllUsersOfGroup(GroupName).Wait();`

Comment: can you edit your question to include that and any other relevant code?

Comment: @stuartd I updated the Post and that is all i am trying to do..

Comment: @stuartd Any Suggestions on the same ..Please guide me ..